# How to fetch data from database table which is connected to AspNetUsers table in mvc 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have added **DepartmentId** column as Foreign Key in **AspNetUsers** table and also i have the same **DepartmentId** as ForeignKey in another table called **MaterialRequest**  i want login user's Department Name to be displayed in the View As 'Department Name'

My Classes

**Department**

DepartmentId
DepartmentName

**MaterialRequest**

MaterialRequestId
MaterialName
DepartmentId

What i have tried

```
        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
  var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            ViewBag.DeptName=db.Query<AspNetUser>("Select DepartmentId from AspNetUsers where Id = '@0'",id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way around this, you can create a claim and get this way:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
    // Add custom user claims here => this.DepartmentId is a value stored in database against the user
    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("DepartmentId", this.DepartmentId.ToString()));

        return userIdentity;
    }

    // Your Extended Properties
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Then create an extension method to get your departmentId:

```
namespace App.Extensions
{
    public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static string GetDepartmentId(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("DepartmentId");
            // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can easily call this method to get your DepartmentId:

```
var departmentId= User.Identity.GetDepartmentId();
```

Comment: ok but how can i show the departmentname in which user is login

Comment: @kunals since you are passing your Identity you don't have to pass the userId to this. basically whomever is logged in will get their own DepartmentId. works like `User.Identity.GetUserId()`

Comment: var departmentId= User.Identity.GetDepartmentId(); with this we are getting the departmentid which the logged in user belongs but how to display that departmentname to my view

Comment: @kunals easy there are many ways to achieve this, one would be passing it with a model to your view. another one would be passing it via a ViewBag/TempData etc... or there is actually easier way just to call method within your view you just need to add `@using App.Extensions` at the top then call the method within razor. since its static method its easy to achieve.

Comment: with VIewBag how can i display it

Comment: @kunals within your controller `ViewBag.DepartmentId = User.Identity.GetDepartmentId();` then in your view `@ViewBag.DepartmentId` thats it.

Comment: @kunals i don't know how to explain it more to you maybe u need to learn more about asp.net mvc and asp.net identity